# LocalStorage on HTML 4 website in modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I was thinking about writing a JS wrapper to have an HTML 5 `localStorage` object on older websites using HTML 4, because everybody says its only available with HTML 5. So I wrote up [this simple page](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7Vh/):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log(localStorage);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

... and I expected the console to give me an `undefined` so I can start implementing. But it just shows the local storage object, which I can use normally! I tried it on latest version of Chrome, Safari and Firefox, and it just works.

So my Q is:

**Do I miss something or is `localStorage` usable in modern browsers regardless of the doctype stating HTML4 or HTML5?**

Is it just not known that this works? Works for me... but why is everybody talking about HTML 5 being a requirement then? I did not find any source stating this just works in HTML4.

Comment: it was ADDED in HTML5, and to browsers that support HTML5 no matter what document they are rendering, compat and security restrictions aside. HTML5 elements and APIs don't care about the doctype...

Comment: Web browsers are very forgiving.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how were you going to add support if local storage isn't supported?

Comment: @meagar I think the only possible way(without plugins or something) would be cookies

Comment: HTML4 specification does not say that localstorage should not be available.

Comment: @meagar I thought about an iframe containing an HTML5 document and then accessing this from the parent... but seems like this is unneccessary ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that localStorage is attributed to HTML 5 is not because of the HTML 5 doctype, but rather because it requires an HTML 5 compatible BROWSER.  It is the browser that determines if the features are present to create and maintain local storage.

Please see the following link for some interesting information regarding client-side storage:
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage

Comment: Pretty much this. The browser doesn't disable newer JS APIs based on your doctype.

Comment: But this clearly states that "Without HTML5, client-side storage for web applications is limited to the tiny storage provided by cookies" This information is very misleading in my opinion then...

Comment: @migg It is insinuating HTML 5 spec browsers, which is the context of the article.  It in no way refers to the doctype of the document being rendered.

Comment: So in every article "HTML5" is referring to a "modern browser", not the doctype?

Comment: saying "HTML5" is a bit of a catch-all term. HTML5 isn't something you turn on or off - it generally refers to a very wide range of features that all browsers have been including. Many of these features, like CSS3, or many Javascript APIs, cannot be "turned off" since they don't cause issues just by being 'available'. Also, I should note a number of libraries have provided APIs to simulate localStorage in older browsers (even going back to IE5, without using cookies!)

Comment: @migg Although you can never say "every" as an absolute, in general, yes, it is referring to the browser, not the doctype.  This may be a misnomer but often is the case in the web :)

Comment: @DavidL fair enough... so then I was missing **that** :)

Answer (score 0):

Web Storage was conceived as a part of the HTML 5 specification.  Since then, however, both HTML5 and Web Storage are being developed simultaneously as separate standards, neither of which are yet finalized.  As a result, Web Storage could work with older versions of HTML, but only modern browsers can support either standard.